# Make woocommerce booking extension automatically bookable on products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My Question is to automatically make all the products set to bookable using Woocommerce Booking Extension by Woothemes. I just purchased this expensive plugin but i want to make ALL products bookable since all my products are already bookable. I need to set them all at one, instead of going through each product and set it manually. This is because we have lots of products in this business and going through product one by one would take time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer its easy for you to code the to make the products bookable whenever a new product is create( In this case the code from [this](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/creating-bookings-programatically/) link would be useful for you).

Or else add a new bulk action to woocommerce saying 'Make Bookable' , here you will get all the selected product's ids and for the same you have to check and create bookings.

Comment: I am trying to create a booking something like this: http://103.15.234.46/~gogospac/listing/jade-cafe-de-cafe/
with duration month, type and start month. Tell me if you can do this i am willing to pay $30 if this could be easy to code on your part.